# Code Mappings : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using nHibernate 3.3.1.4 with Code Mappings.

Have Person and Picture objects, where Person have a Picture member.
Picture have an Id (int) and Image (byte[]) members.
When uploading a new picture, I want to delete the old picture first as follows:

```
var person = _personRepository.Get(personId);
var picture = partner.Picutre;
_pictureRepository.Delete(picture);
```

However it seems my mappings are incorrect, since I get an error about "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint....."

Here is my mappings:

```
mapper.Class<Person>(map => map.ManyToOne(x => x.Picture, pic => pic.Cascade(Cascade.DeleteOrphans)));

mapper.Class<Picture>(map => map.Property(x => x.Image, x => x.Type(NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo just need to set `partner.Picutre` to `null`

```
var picture = partner.Picutre;
partner.Picutre = null
_pictureRepository.Delete(picture);
```

And here you done.

Comment: I had that before, and just changed back.  No error, but while the Person's PictureFk field are set to null, the image in the Pictures table are not being deleted.

Comment: I mean you have to place it between `var picture = partner.Picutre;` and `_pictureRepository.Delete(picture);`. I will update example.